# Using Android ML-Kit Bird Classifier with Python

Tags: python, android, machine-learning

I tested the Android Vision Quick Start App from the ML Kit. As you can see in the picture, object tracking is possible here. Now I'm trying the same model (bird_classifier.tflite) with Python. This works very well, but how do I get the bounding boxes here? Whatever I do, the feedback is: The model includes only one Tensor. But why does it work in the Android app?
Can someone show me a code example for this?

[image: Test Image]

```py
image = Image.fromarray(screenshot)
image_pred = image.resize((width ,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
results = classify_image(interpreter, image_pred)
# TrackingID = results[i0][0]
# Score = results[i0][1]
# Boxes = ?
```